# How to join every value in one dataframe to every row in another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to insert the same information beside every row using pandas. For example, I have a dataframe with columns: Name, Age. and another datafreme with only one column: COLOR, and i would like to combine both as below:

[image]

Comment: cross join/merge: `df1.assign(dummy=1).merge(df2.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')`.

Comment: You should insert code to reproduce the issue or question, not images.

Answer (score 3):

You want the Cartesian product of the data frames. Use

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Comment: First time I heard of `how='cross'` option. This is new in `1.2.0`.

Comment: it is asking me to fill the data 'on'. follow the error 'MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False'

Comment: @rodrigoeduardo try this?